# Live CD from Scratch - No vmlinuz* / initrd.img*

Tags: custom-distributions

Following this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

When it asks:

> cp chroot/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.**-**-generic image/casper/vmlinuz
>
> cp chroot/boot/initrd.img-2.6.**-**-generic image/casper/initrd.lz

I don't have such files:

> ls chroot/boot
>
> grub memtest86+.bin memtest86+.elf memtest86+_multiboot.bin

Is the guide out of date or did I miss a step?

Edit:

As per my comment below I am doing:

`sudo debootstrap --arch=$ARCH $RELEASE chroot`

Where amd64 and trusty are the values.

Comment: Need more info.  What version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you do the "dpkg --install YourVersionHere"?

Comment: @Fabby thanks 14.04. I don't see `dpkg --install YourVersionHere` in these instructions

Comment: It says "Find the version of debootstrap you need here and install it using dpkg".  That's the step you missed.
If you give me your version,I'll give you the  exact command to type...

Comment: @Fabby debootstrap is installed, that part works fine. As per the page I run `sudo debootstrap --arch=$ARCH $RELEASE chroot` with amd64 and trusty as the values. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The guide is outdated and is based on the 2.6.x-x kernel. I assume that you are running a newer kernel version since this question was asked recently.

For Trusty Tahr, 64-bit -

`sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 trusty chroot`

To check your kernel version, type the following in a Terminal -

`uname -r`

Now replace `2.6.x-x` with your kernel version. eg-`3.13.0-37`.

```
cp chroot/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-37-generic image/casper/vmlinuz

cp chroot/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-37-generic image/casper/initrd.lz
```

Comment: As per my comment above I am already running `sudo debootstrap --arch=amd64 trusty chroot`, I also state the output of `ls boot` within chroot which shows these files don't exist.